# How to open a 30gb or more wireshark file (.pcap) from system which is having a low configuration?

Tags: 14.04, wireshark

I have few wireshark file (.pcap) which is more than 30gb. And I having a system of low configuration (4GB RAM, 500GB HDD etc).
So how can I open the same .pcap file and able to analyse the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it is appropriate to split the file

Comment: But how you will split the file ? any idea

Comment: The first idea is to use console program called `split`. But the success will depend on `.pcap` format specification. The second idea is to write your own `bash` or `python` script which will consider different features of the `.pcap` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. The way is to use `tcpdump` program.

```
tcpdump -r old_file -w new_files -C 10
```

10 - is the size of new files in million bytes. 10 Mb in this example

Comment: Thanks will try the same. But how that 30 gb file will gets converted into 10 Mb. Means will that 10 Mb file contains all the data and contents of the old file

Comment: There are many 10 MB files